# syntax error in user model - dynamic table names - Laravel

Tags: php, database, session, symfony, laravel

I am trying to set it up so that my user model accesses a different table depending on which organisation the user is from. The session is set just before i call the auth attempt function and i know for a fact it contains a value at the time it's used. I have no idea why i get a syntax error here, it all looks fine to me(syntax wise).

I have this in my user model

```
public $table = Session::get('council').'_data';
```

and I get this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

public $table is a class attribute, try to set his content from inside a class method.

```
public function my_method(){
    $this->table = Session::get('council').'_data';
}
```

Comment: I can't really do this because i have no idea where the user object gets created in the login process so i can't call that method without having the User object first that will be used to Auth the user.

Comment: public function __construct()
    {
     $this->table = Session::get('council').'_data';
    }

I just added it to the construct of the user model and it all works perfectly.

Thanks gadz82 you pointed me in the right direction.